# How do I remove \n from my python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a text file that is something like:

```
apples,green
tomatos,red
bananas,yellow
```

and my code to use this as a dictionary is

```
def load_list(filename):
    with open(filename, "rU") as my_file:
        my_list = {}
        for line in my_file:
            x = line.split(",")
            key = x[0]
            value = x[1]
            my_list[key] = value
        print my_list
```

which works fine, except that every value has \n added to the end of it, because of the line break. I tried adding

```
.strip()
```

to the x attribute, but it reulsted in an attribute error (AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip').

So how do I remove the \n?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should `strip` before splitting, like this

```
x = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
```

we use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) here, because we just need to eliminate the newlines at the end of the line.

Also, you can unpack the key and values straight away, like this

```
key, value = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example illustrating how the strip can be used generally:

```
def main():
# Open a file named football.txt.
infile = open('football.txt', 'r')

# Read three lines from the file.
line1 = infile.readline()
line2 = infile.readline()
line3 = infile.readline()

Strip the \n from each string.
line1 = line1.rstrip('\n')
line2 = line2.rstrip('\n')
line3 = line3.rstrip('\n')

# Close the file.
infile.close()

# Print the data that was read into memory.
print(line1)
print(line2)
print(line3)

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Let's say that you wanted to read things into a list and strip off the newline. You could do the following:

```
# This program reads a file's contents into a list.

def main():
# Open a file for reading.
infile = open('football.txt', 'r')

# Read the contents of the file into a list.
football = infile.readlines()

# Close the file.
infile.close()

# Strip the \n from each element.
index = 0
while index < len(football):
football[index] = football[index].rstrip('\n')
index += 1

# Print the contents of the list.
print(football)

# Call the main function.
main()
```

This second program version could easily substitute the list for a dictionary with only a few very minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this is one of the problems you can avoid if you use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), because it will strip the lines for you:

```
import csv

def load_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        my_dict = {k:v for k,v in reader}
    return my_dict
```

I also changed the name of your variable to `my_dict` since its not a list.